# Get week period based on week number, month and year sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to get the first day and the last day of the week based on the number of the week, year and month

My week starts on saturday and finish in friday
Example:
Year: 2020
Week: 45

> Normal period of week: First day: 2020-10-31 ~ Last day: 2020-11-06

I need return something like

> October: First day: 2020-10-31 ~ last day: 2020-10-31
>
> November: First day 2020-11-01 ~ last day: 2020-11-06

my query to return last day of week:

```
select DATEADD (WEEK, @PcpSemana, DATEADD (YEAR,  ('20' + LEFT(@PcpPeriodo,2))-1900, 0)) - 5 as lastDayOfWeek
```

my query to return first day of week

```
SELECT WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY, 
                        (CEILING(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD (WEEK, @PcpSemana, DATEADD (YEAR,  ('20' + LEFT(@PcpPeriodo,2))-1900, 0)) - 5) / 7.0) - 1) * 7,
                        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,DATEADD (WEEK, @PcpSemana, DATEADD (YEAR,  ('20' + LEFT(@PcpPeriodo,2))-1900, 0)) - 5), 0));
```

I'm using SET DATEFIRST 6
I can't evolve much

PcpPeriodo contains YYMM ( 2011) = 2020 / 11 )
PcpSemana contains weeknumber (45) (01 ~ 53)

Comment: Why does your first example start and end of the same day? If you have odd week numberings, you'll likely want to create a calendar table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your data looks like, but if you have the first day of the week, you can split it among months as:

```
select weeks.*
from (values (convert(date, '2020-10-31'))) w(weekstart) cross apply
     (values (dateadd(day, 6, w.weekstart), eomonth(w.weekstart))
     ) v(weekend, eom) cross apply
     (values (w.weekstart,
              case when v1.weekend <= v1.eom then v1.weekend else v1.eom end
             ),
             (case when v1.weekend > v1.eom then dateadd(day, 1, v1.eom) end,
              case when v1.weekend > 1.eom then v1.weekend
             )
      ) weeks(weekstart, weekend)
where weeks.weekstart is not null;
```

This is using `apply` as a way of storing intermediate results, such as the last day of the month and when the week ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @d datetime;

SET DATEFIRST 6;
SET @d = '2020-11-01';

WITH weektest as (
  select @d as d
  union all
  select DATEADD(DAY,1,d) from weektest where d<='2020-11-6'
)
SELECT 
   d, 
   DATEPART(week, d), 
   DATEPART(weekday,d),
   DATENAME(weekday,d)
from weektest;
```

output:

```
d                                               
----------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------
2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 45          2           Sunday
2020-11-02 00:00:00.000 45          3           Monday
2020-11-03 00:00:00.000 45          4           Tuesday
2020-11-04 00:00:00.000 45          5           Wednesday
2020-11-05 00:00:00.000 45          6           Thursday
2020-11-06 00:00:00.000 45          7           Friday
2020-11-07 00:00:00.000 46          1           Saturday
```